# Interpolation between two matrices so that $L^p$ norm is controlled

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, interpolation

Assume to have two square matrices $A$ and $B$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that all their entries are in the interval $[0,1]$ and such that $||Ax||_1 = ||x||_1$ and $||Bx||_\infty \leq ||x||_\infty$. I wonder if there is a "standard" way to construct some matrix $C$ from $A$ and $B$ such that $||Cx||_p \leq K||x||_p$ for some universal $K$ (not dependent on $p$) and such that $C \to A$ if $p \to 1$ and $C \to B$ if $p \to + \infty$. I can't find any interpolation results online about this type of problem.

Answer (score 6):

The constraint that $||Ax||_1 = ||x||_1$ is actually a *very* strong constraint. It actually implies that $A$ is a signed-permutation matrix, that is the matrix $A \in \{-1,0,1\}^{n \times n}$ and $A$ has exactly one non-zero entry in each row and each column.

The additional constraint that the entries of $A$ are contained in $[0,1]$ actually forces $A$ to be a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), that is $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ and $A$ has exactly one 1 in each row and each column.

One implication of this is that $\|Ax\|_p = \|x\|_p$ for every $p \geq 1$. This is because if $\sigma$ is the permutation corresponding to $A$ in the sense that $Ax = (x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})$ then
$$\|Ax\|_p^p = \sum_{i=1}^n |(Ax)_i|^p = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_{\sigma(i)}|^p = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p = \|x\|_p^p.$$

**Updated Complete Answer** After a long think, I've come up with an interpolation of the two matrices which may be sufficient.

For $p \geq 1$ define $C(p) = (1- \lambda(p))A + \lambda(p)B$
where
$$\lambda(p) = \frac{1}{n^{1/p}} - \frac{1}{pn}$$
This specifically so that it has the following properties

1. $\lambda(1) = 0$ which ensures $C(1) = A$
2. $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \lambda(p) = 1$ which ensures $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} C(p) = B$
3. $\lambda$ is smoothly monotonically increasing on $[1,\infty)$
4. $\lambda(p) < \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}$ for all $p \in [1,\infty)$.

The last part is essential because of the inequality
\begin{align}\|x\|_p &= \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p \right )^{1/p} \\
&= \|x\|_\infty \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{|x_i|}{\|x\|_\infty }\right)^p \right )^{1/p} \\
&\leq \|x\|_\infty \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n 1^p \right )^{1/p} = \|x\|_\infty n^{1/p}
\end{align}
Applying this with $\lambda(p)Bx$ gives
\begin{align}
\|\lambda(p)Bx\|_p &= \lambda(p)\|Bx\|_p \\
&\leq \lambda(p) n^{1/p}\|Bx\|_\infty \\
&\leq \left ( \frac{1}{n^{1/p}} \right )n^{1/p}\|x\|_\infty \\
&= \|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_p.
\end{align}
Combining these facts with Minkowski's inequality gives the bound
\begin{align}
    \|C(p)x\|_p &= \|(1-\lambda(p))Ax + \lambda(p)Bx\|_p \\
    &\leq \|(1-\lambda(p))Ax\|_p + \|\lambda(p)Bx\|_p \\
    &\leq (1-\lambda(p))\|Ax\|_p + \|x\|_p \\
    &= (1-\lambda(p))\|x\|_p + \|x\|_p \leq 2\|x\|_p
\end{align}
which shows that this choice of $C(p)$ interpolates between $A$ and $B$ and satisfies the bound with $K = 2$.

---

We will prove that $A$ is a signed-permutation matrix in several steps.

**Step 1** $A$ is full rank.

*Proof:* Suppose that $A$ was not full rank and let $x \neq 0$ be such that $Ax = 0$. Then we would have
$$\|x\|_1 \neq 0 = \|Ax\|_1$$
which is a contradiction with the assumption on $A$.

**Step 2** Let $B_1^n := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ \|x\|_1 \leq 1\}$. Then $x \mapsto Ax$ is a bijection from $B_1^n$ onto itself. Similarly, let $S_1^n := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ \|x\|_1 = 1\}$. Then $x \mapsto Ax$ is a bijection from $S_1^n$ onto itself.

*Proof:* To start we have for all $x \in B_1^n$
$$1 \geq \|x\|_1 = \|Ax\|_1 \implies Ax \in B_1^n$$
so that the image of the map is at least contained in $B_1^n$.

Next let $x,x' \in B_1^n$ so that
$$0 < \|x - x'\|_1 = \|A(x - x')\|_1 = \|Ax - Ax'\|_1$$
which shows $Ax \neq Ax'$ and therefore $x \mapsto Ax$ is injective.

For surjectivity we will use Step 1. Since $A$ is full rank $A^{-1}$ exists. In particular for every $x \in B_1^n$ we have
$$x = (AA^{-1})x = A(A^{-1}x)$$
and also
$$1 \geq \|x\|_1 = \|A(A^{-1}x)\|_1 = \|A^{-1}x\|_1 \implies A^{-1}x \in B_1^n$$
In particular for every $x \in B_1^n$ it is the image of $A^{-1}x \in B_1^n$ under $A$. This shows $x \mapsto Ax$ is also surjective from $B_1^n$ onto itself.

Having established injectivity and surjectivity we conclude that $x \mapsto Ax$ is a bijection. The argument for $S_1^n$ is essentially the same.

**Step 3** If $x = e_i$ for some $i=1,...,n$ then $Ax \in \{\pm e_1,...,\pm e_n\}$ where $e_1,...,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors.

*Proof:* Assume without loss of generality that $x = e_1$ and suppose for contradiction that $Ax \notin \{\pm e_1,...,\pm e_n\}$. Since $x \mapsto Ax$ is a bijection of $S_1^n$ onto itself there are $2n$ distinct points $z^1,...,z^{2n} \in S_1^n$ such that $\{Az^1,...,Az^{2n}\} = \{\pm e_1,...,\pm e_n\}$. Since $e_1$ is not in the set $\{z^1,...,z^{2n}\}$ and there are exactly $2n$ points in $S_1^n$ with precisely one non-zero entry, there must be a $z \in \{z^1,...,z^{2n}\}$ with two or more non-zero entries. The contradiction we will reach is that $\|Az\|_2 < 1$ and therefore $Az \notin \{\pm e_1,...,\pm e_n\}$.

Without loss of generality assume that this is $z^1$ and the non-zero entries are $z^1_1,...,z^1_k$ for some $k > 1$. Now note that we can write $z^1$ as
$$z^1 = \sum_{i=1}^k z^1_i e_i.$$

Let's recall a classic inequality.

> Let $b^1,...,b^k$ be non-zero vectors for $k > 1$. Then
> $$\left \| \sum_{i=1}^k b^i \right \|_2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^l \|b^1\|_2 $$
> and there is equality if and only if $b^i = c_ib^1$ where $c^i > 0$.

Next note that since $e_1,...,e_k \in S_1^n$ and $x \mapsto Ax$ is a bijection of $S_1^n$ onto itself we have $Ae_1,...,Ae_k \in S_1^n$. In addition we can conclude that $Ae_i \neq cAe_j$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ for any pair $i \neq j$:

- $c$ cannot be 1 because $Ae_i \neq Ae_j$ by injectivity
- $c$ cannot be $-1$ since $(-1)Ae_i = A(-e_i)$ and $A(-e_i) \neq Ae_j$ by injectivity.
- $c$ cannot be any other value because then either $\|Ae_i\|_1 \neq 1$ or $\|Ae_j\|_1 \neq 1$

From this we can conclude that for any $t_1,...,t_k \neq 0$ we have
\begin{align}
\left \| \sum_{i=1}^k At_ie_i \right \|_2 
&= \left \| \sum_{i=1}^k t_i(Ae_i) \right \|_2 \\ 
&< \sum_{i=1}^k \|t_iAe_i\|_2 
\end{align}
and the inequality is strict because $t_iAe_i$ are all non-zero and $t_1Ae_1 \neq ct_iAe_i$ for any $i = 2,3,...,k$. In particular with $t_i = z^1_i$ we have
\begin{align}
\left \| \sum_{i=1}^k Az^1_ie_i \right \|_2
&<  \sum_{i=1}^k \|Az^1_ie_i\|_2 \\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^k |z^1_i|\|Ae_i\|_2 \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^k |z^1_i|\|Ae_i\|_1 \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^k |z^1_i|\|e_i\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^k |z^1_i| = \|z^1\|_1 = 1 
\end{align}

Overall we have established that $\|Az^1\|_2 < 1$. Finally this shows that $Az^1 \notin \{\pm e_1,...,\pm e_n\}$, which is the contradiction we sought.

**Step 4** $A$ is a signed-permutation matrix.

By Step 3 we have for every $i=1,...,n$ that $Ae_i = \pm e_j$. This shows that the $i$'th column of $A$ is precisely $\pm e_j$ and therefore every column has exactly one non-zero entry, and additionally there are $n$ non-zero entries. If two non-zero entries are in the same row then there is a row with no entries, and as a result $A$ is not full rank which would contradict Step 1. This concludes the proof that $A$ is a signed permutation matrix.

Comment: Nice answer! As a side note, the fact that $A$ is what you call a signed permutation matrix is a special case of the Banach-Lamperti theorem that characterizes isometries of $L^p$ for $p\neq 2$.

Comment: Thanks! I actually forgot to specify a very important detail in the question, i.e. I am talking about probabilities, so everything is non negative. Anyway, the question can be generalised on how to interpolate between two different continuous linear operators, in general

Comment: I just figured out a viable interpolation and have updated the answer to include it. I'm sure that there are probably many more as well.